# How to use Metrics for non-blocking implementation

Tags: performance, nonblocking, metrics

I like to get an idea of how we can use metrics for non-blocking methods. Is it possible? Please give some idea.
In normally i used metrics as follows

```
public void methodRequest(){
  final Timer.Context context=responses.time();
  try{
    doWorks.
  } finally{
    context.stop();
  }
}
```

Can we get metrics in a similar way for the non-blocking methods